# Not able to save if Mongoose Schema(req.body) is an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using Angular 6 js as Client side framework. From Client req.body data 
 which is sent to server is an array of objects
     **[ { email: 'Testserver' },
       { email: 'Liveserver' }]**

But when I save no data is being saved in the collection.An empty 
   emailServer array is being saved.Any suggestions where am I going wrong?

**app.js file-:**

```
    const MongooseSchema = require('../models/mongoose')

     app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
     var obj = new MongooseSchema(req.body);
      obj.save((err,success)=>{
       if(err){
           res.send(err)
       }
       res.send(success)
     })
```

**mongoose.js file**

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


   var MongooseSchema = new Schema({

    emailServer : [{
    email : {type:String}

    }]

    },{ collection: "RegisteredUserDetails" })


    module.exports = mongoose.model('MongooseSchema',MongooseSchema)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the document you're creating has to match what's defined in your schema. The posted data doesn't include the `emailServer` field name, so you need to add that:

```
var obj = new MongooseSchema({emailServer: req.body});
```